# Get list of acive formatters using the VSCode API

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, formatter

I'm working on an extension that acts as a formatting provider and I would like to implement some functionality that checks whether other Python formatters are also active, and confirms that my formatter is activated and registered.

The extension registers the formatter with `vscode.languages.registerDocumentFormattingEditProvider`, but I can't see a way to access a list of active formatters or even check if the registered formatter is properly configured. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I would be surprised if this is possible. You could try opening a feature request for it, but I'm not sure it's something that would be prioritized.

Comment: There _is_ a list of active extensions in the API, but I don't think there's really a way to know if those extensions registered a formatting provider, let alone if it's active.